# Problema con el contexto en proyecto Spring MVC y URL's

Tags: spring-mvc

soy desarrollador Java pero es la primera vez que me toca crear un proyecto web desde 0 y elegir las tecnologias a usar. He eledigo Spring MVC porque es lo que mas he usado pero ahora que estoy haciendo y configurando el proyecto en NetBeans me he topado con bastantes dolores de cabeza, aqui muestro uno para que ojalá me puedan ayudar.

Mi proyecto se llama AdminConsole y al crearlo puse dentro de la carpeta web los recursos (.css .js .img, etc). Desde el jsp hago referencia a esos recursos asi "href='img/imagen.jpg'" inclusive tengo configurado Spring MVC por anotaciones para que siempre entre cada peticion por un controller, y cada peticion la hago asi "form action='/procesarForm'" y me funcionaba.

Un dia sin absolutamente nada que hacerle llego al trabajo y ya no detecta el contexto. (*ya me habia pasado pero creaba siempre un nuevo proyecto*).

Ahora la forma para que funcione es agregando el contexto en cada URL asi sea para llamar recursos como css o img como para peticiones de spring.
ejemplo ${contextPath}/img/imagen.jpg o ${contextPath}/procesarForm.

En el navegador muestra el error que no se encuentra la ruta para esos archivos http://localhost:8080/css/style.css etc. cuando antes no habia problema.

¿Podrian ayudarme porfavor? a continuación muestro los archivos mas relevantes de mi proyecto.

Esta es la estructura de carpetas que tengo:

[image: Estructura de Carpetas]

Este es mi web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/</welcome-file>        
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"        
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"   
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd         
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd        
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd        
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-util-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
            
    <!--
        Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
        for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
        define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/pages/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />
          
    <!-- Especificamos el o los paquetes donde estan los controllers -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven /> <!-- Especificamos que los controllers funcionaran con anotaciones -->
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />   <!--Especificamos que Spring detecte el servlet por default para la carga inicial -->
          
    <!-- INTERNACIONALIZACION -->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages" /> <!-- Ubucacion de los archivos .properties con los labels -->
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" /> <!-- Idioma por Default -->      
    </bean>
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="locale" /> <!-- Variable para interceptar el cambio de idioma -->
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>

</beans>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView login(){ //Metodo que se ejecuta antes de cargar el Login            
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();            
    model.setViewName("login");

    return model;
}
```

JSP:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Creative - Bootstrap 3 Responsive Admin Template">
    <meta name="author" content="GeeksLabs">
    <meta name="keyword" content="Creative, Dashboard, Admin, Template, Theme, Bootstrap, Responsive, Retina, Minimal">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->    
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- bootstrap theme -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--external css-->
    <!-- font icon -->
    <link href="css/elegant-icons-style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Custom styles -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <title>Admin Console</title>
</head>
```

Creo que el error debe ser que tengo configurado mal el web.xml ya que lo tengo para que capte todas las peticiones y las pase por un controller, pero no se porque sin moverle nada funciona y sin mas ya no, ya llevo varios proyectos que creo nuevos cada vez que hace este error.

Estare eternamente agradecido con su ayuda.

Comment: Tienes puesto el `@Controller` o `@RestController` en la clase del Controlador?

Answer (score 1):

Por la url que has comentado (http://localhost:8080/css/style.css) parece que has modificado tu servidor web para que sirva tu aplicación desde la raiz omitiendo el nombre de la aplicación. Esto puede afectar a tus enlaces si no los has estado construyendo correctamente. Precisamente para evitar estos problemas, es buena práctica usar siempre contextPath en la construcción de tus urls o en su defecto

```
<c:url value="/url_relativa"/>
```

Igualmente, te aconsejaría que si usas spring-mvc, dejes que él sirva el contenido estático de manera más eficiente, incluyendo en tu **dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
 <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
```

Espero que te sirva